# Android Socket Server problems

Tags: android, sockets

My group and I are using a simple java server to run our game. All it does is get info from one client and give it to the other. We can get the client to connect to the server but when we have it return a successful connection to the client, it will not return. We were told to use android handlers and threads to fix this. We think we are using the thread part correctly but need some help with the android handlers.

```
public int connect(String hostName, int portNum){
//this connects to the server

//Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

  host = hostName;
  port = portNum;
  lock = 1;
  this.start();
  String response;
  while(lock == 1){
      try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

try{
    response = in.readLine();
    if(Integer.parseInt(response)==1){
      player = 1;
    }else{
      player = 2;
    }
  }catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("Error!");
    return -1;
  }

return player;
```

}

```
public void run(){ 
  try{  
      server = new Socket(host, port);
      out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
  }catch(IOException e){
      System.out.println("Error!");
  }
  lock = 0;}
```

Comment: Have you got some code to show?

Comment: which part do you need to see we know that the server works as we can use it correctly on two desktops

Comment: Socket connection etc. It may help others find the problem - right now they can more or less only guess.

Comment: Server should use ServerSocket, Client should use Socket; Server gets the Socket. What parts blocks? The client can't connect to the server? Server don't get the connection from the client?